# Conforming to protocols from categories in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C, why is it if you have a category for a class, and conform to a protocol in the category, why does the main class not know you conform to that category?

For example, some pseudo code

main class file

```
@implementation SessionManager

[SessionManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self]; // warning from Xcode saying that SessionManager is not the appropriate type
```

category file

```
@interface SessionManager (SomeCategory) <SessionManagerProtocol>
```

But if I just move the declaration of the conformance to the protocol in the main class file

```
@interface SessionManager : NSObject <SessionManagerProtocol>
```

The compiler does not generate a warning in that case.  Is it just best to declare your conformance in the main class file?

Comment: Please add `SessionManagerProtocol` methods

Comment: @trungduc Sorry I wrote the wrong error message. It's not because I'm not conforming to the protocol, because those methods are declared in the main class. But it's complaining that I'm saying my object is of that protocol type and it's incompatible with that type. It complains about that if the protocol declaration is in a category. But if I just add the conformance to the main class where I say `=self`, then it has no problem since it sees I am declaring conformance there. Sorry if that was not clear in my original question.

Comment: Did you import category `.h` file in main class `.m` file?

Comment: Ah sorry I’m dumb. Thanks. I’ll market answered if u put it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import category `.h` file in main class `.m` file so that complier can know these methods were declared in class category and it won't show warning.